# "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax" when I alter a table

Tags: mysql

When I try to alter a table I got this error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1

Here is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE gk
ADD COLUMN id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: are you running this query in my sql workbench or from java?

Comment: try to add new column in my table

Comment: -1: Basic failure to read the documentation. Lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `ALTER TABLE` statement, a single `ADD` specification can't add both a column and a constraint; you'll need to put them in separate specifications:

```
ALTER TABLE gk ADD COLUMN id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
               ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

(See [§13.1.6 "`ALTER TABLE` Syntax" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).)

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE gk  ADD id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: `When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think you're misunderstanding that. Firstly -- it's about `CHANGE` and `MODIFY`, not `ADD`. Secondly -- it means that index attributes are *optional* (and not implicitly removed), not that index attributes are *forbidden* (and not addable).

Comment: @ruakh: Oh yes it's `ADD`; missed that. Not sure about the other thing -- I parse it differently. But only testing would disambiguate it and I cba :) Also I'll take your word for it.